# Where to find older versions of Blender?

Tags: versions

I have got the *"Blender for Dummies"* book from late 2016 and would like to ask where to find an appropriate **old** version of Blender?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the official links for old Blender releases:

- https://download.blender.org/release/
- https://www.blender.org/download/releases/